# Spring gem loaded in wrong environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile, spring-gem

Why does my spring gem load in the wrong (or all) environment(s)?

I have this in my Gemfile and spring gem is not listed anywhere else in the file:

```
group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.1.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

When I ran `bundle exec rails console test` (for the `test` environment), spring processes started and the `Listen` module was loaded in the rails console. I made sure all spring processes were stopped beforehand.

To do a sanity check, I removed the whole development group above and bundled.  Spring and listen gems were no longer loaded, as I expected.

Comment: Is it possible that there is a `RAILS_ENV` variable initialized? Also what version of bundler are you using?

Comment: bundle version 1.15.4. No, RAILS_ENV is not set. Although, I've tried `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails console` with same issue. From rails console, I also verified `Rails.env` and `Gem::Specification.all_names` (list of loaded gems)

Answer (score 5):

I faced this misunderstanding in production.

**Here's how I solved it:**

You can also fix this issue **permanently** by upspringing (removing the spring gem from) your `bin/` executables:

```
bin/spring binstub --remove --all
```

Or

```
spring binstub --remove --all
```

You can now run the command below to get into rails console in production

```
rails c --environment=production
```

Also, to avoid this from occurring in subsequent occasions endeavour to make sure that the [spring](https://rubygems.org/gems/spring) gem is only present in `development` and `test` groups in your Gemfile.

Moreso, when you're in production make sure you always provide the `--without development test` argument to the `bundle install` command

```
bundle install --without development test
```

and not the usual or common

```
bundle install
```

**Please note:** As an indication, whenever you run the command `rails c` or `rails console` and you see the output below:

> Running via Spring preloader in process 26651
>   WARNING: Spring is running in production. To fix this make sure the spring gem is only present in `development` and `test` groups in your Gemfile and make sure you always use `bundle install --without development test` in production

It's an indication that the [spring](https://rubygems.org/gems/spring) gem is running in your production environment, and it should be stopped or removed entirely from your bin executables.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 1):

Spring is generally used through binstubs - did you install the binstubs? If so this is the file your `rails` command is running through.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

As you can see it will load `spring` anytime you use the `rails` command. There is no check for the environment. If you do not want to load `spring` you can use `DISABLE_SPRING=1 rails c test`.

Comment: I'm running `rails` through `bundle exec rails`, not through the binstubs I don't think. Regardless, it's scary that spring is overriding the rule of the Gemfile environment group.

Comment: Adding that begin/rescue/end fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

According the [spring gem github page](https://github.com/rails/spring#rails-console-rails-generate-rails-runner), it looks like `rails console` will load up spring:

> rails console, rails generate, rails runner
>
> These execute the rails command you already know and love. If you run
>   a different sub command (e.g. rails server) then spring will
>   automatically pass it through to the underlying rails executable
>   (without the speed-up).

Also, this is worrying:

> You must not install Spring on your production environment. To
>   prevent it from being installed, provide the --without development
>   test argument to the bundle install command

`rails console` (development) would make sense, but not `rails console test` (or another environment). It seems buggy to me, and a reason now why I don't like the gem.